# sudo update-ca-certificates always add new cert

Tags: debian, ssl, certificates

When I run sudo update-ca-certificates on debian 8
it is always add one new cert. it is normal behavior? What's can be wrong?

```
ar@work:/tmp$ sudo update-ca-certificates 
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

done.
Updating Mono key store
Linux Cert Store Sync - version 4.2.1.0
Synchronize local certs with certs from local Linux trust store.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

I already trust 174, your new list has 175
Certificate added: C=IL, O=StartCom Ltd., OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing, CN=StartCom Certification Authority
1 new root certificates were added to your trust store.
Import process completed.
Done
done.
ar@work:/tmp$ sudo update-ca-certificates 
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

done.
Updating Mono key store
Linux Cert Store Sync - version 4.2.1.0
Synchronize local certs with certs from local Linux trust store.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

I already trust 174, your new list has 175
Certificate added: C=IL, O=StartCom Ltd., OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing, CN=StartCom Certification Authority
1 new root certificates were added to your trust store.
Import process completed.
Done
done.
ar@work:/tmp$
```